# Does character selection affect the stats in any way?

Tags: mario-kart-7

The instruction manual leaves much to be desired. I know the karts themselves affect your stats, but does each player have the same base stats or do they differ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MarioWiki:

> Just as in Mario Kart Wii, each character gets their own specific stat boost that accounts for kart customization, based on their weight class. The units are out of 6.[2] In general, light characters have high values ​​of Acceleration, Handling, and Off-Road, while heavy characters have high values ​​of Speed and Weight. Hover over the weight column to see the characters in the represented weight class.

Here are the different characters unlocked from the beginning and their weight classes:

> **Feather**:
>   Toad, Koopa Troops
>
> **Light**:
>   Peach, Yoshi,
>
> **Medium**:
>   Mario, Luigi
>
> **Cruiser**:
>   Donkey Kong
>
> **Heavy**:
>   Bowser

Unlockable characters:

**Feather**:

> Shy Guy, Lakitu

**Light**:

> Daisy

**Medium**:

> Mii

**Cruiser**:

> Rosalina, Wiggler

**Heavy**:

> Wario, Metal Mario, Honey Queen

[Source](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_7#Character_Bonuses)

Comment: Spoiler tags fail :(

Comment: You can totally make up for the spoiler fail by voting up the question. :P